# WordPress вывод случайного поста из шаблона

Tags: php, wordpress

подскажите как вывести случайный пост из шаблона.

Например есть шаблон.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">


        <?php
            // Тут должен выводиться пост из шаблона single
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Подскажите как такое реализовать?

Comment: Вывести пост из шаблона невозможно. Их там просто нет!

Comment: SeVlad, ну можно построить запрос из шаблона? Ведь верно?

Comment: "Из шаблона" - нет. Твои формулировки говоря что ты вообще не шаришь в ВП. Юзай плаги. Напр. https://wordpress.org/plugins/random-post-shortcode/

Comment: <?php
    query_posts();
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
       <ul>
         <li><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
       </ul>
   <?php  endwhile; endif;
   ?> - так ведь работает, это я вводил в шаблон, список выводится, я вот и спрашиваю как вывести один рандомный пост. Шаблон я имею ввиду php файл в теме(напимер файл поста того же, в моём случае это single.php).

Comment: SeVlad, Вы можете объяснить почему вот этот код не работает? https://hello-site.ru/share/Ne-rabochij-kod/

Comment: https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/ https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part